# Is it a good idea to use browserhostory.push in action helpers?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

In my `React` App I need to take decision based on data I receive from the server.

1. If data is expected ( `Dispatch actions to update state`)
2. If data has error tag ( `browserhistory.push('/notfound');` )
3. If expected data is unable to parsed ( `browserhistory.push('/error');`)

In my app structure, I am using `Redux`, `React-Router` and `React-redux-Router` libraries but no middleware. I have made actionHelpers to making ajax calls and then dispatch appropriate actions using Action Creator. These `actionHelper` methods are exposed in Components to change state. 
My Questions:

1. What's the best way to handle these scenarios ?
2. Is `actionHelper` the best place to take these decisions ?

I don't want to use any middleware for now but please let me know if its a good idea to use middleware to handle these scenarios.

Comment: Whenyou say to change state uou mean the redux state or the component state? And the actionHelpers are just methods that makes the ajax calls?

Comment: if you are already using `react-router-redux`, you can use the `push` that it provides, so your code look cleaner.

Comment: @Pachu, Yes Action helpers are just functions and i am just updating redux state from reducers once action is despatched

Comment: @xiaofan2406 I am using history provided by react-router-redux  to push the state. I just want to see if this is correct approach to handle this or is there any better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actions are not the place where you should do redirections. This behavior should be implemented in the component itself and actions should be left to update the store.

You may want to use the [Redux-thunk middleware](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) here which allows you to dispatch a function (which receives `dispatch` as an argument instead of the object actions. You can then wrap that function in a promise and use it in `componentWillMount`.

In your actions file:

```
updateReduxStore(data) {
  return { 
      type: SOME_TYPE,
      payload: data.something
  };
}

fetchAndValidateData() {
  ...
}

checkData() {
    return function(dispatch) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fetchAndValidateData().then((data) => {
                try {
                    if (JSON.parse(data).length > 0) {
                        dispatch(updateReduxStore(data));
                        resolve('valid data');
                    } else if (data.error) {
                        reject('error in data');
                    }
                }
                catch(err) {
                  reject('malformed data');
                }
            });
        });
    };
}
```

Then in your component:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.checkData()
      .then((message) => {
          console.log(message); //valid data
      })
      .catch((err) => {
          if (err === 'error in data') {
              browserHistory.push('/notfound');
          } else if (err === 'malformed data') {
              browserHistory.push('/error');
          }
      });
}
```

Redux-thunk middleware is made for such use cases.